# How to show values from String Array in p:messages component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I need your help in showing the values from a String Array and to display them in the Messages component in a jsf page.

In the code, I have a `String[]` with below entries:

```
String[] messages = new String[] {
    "Record No.1 Fail",
    "Record No.2 Fail",
    "Record No.3 Success"
};
```

Now I need your help in showing the failed records in the String Array which is called data to the user in the messages component by using the code:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Record No.1 Fail", ""));
 // values from String Array should be passed
```

And the jsf page has:

```
<p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true" closable="true" />
```

Comment: Your question is way to specific. To solve problems, simplify things first, think more generically... What you seem to want is to have 'formatted' text. As you might understand, the 'toString() of an Array is is basic and most likely not formatted in the way you want. So you need to do some basic 'formatting' youself, **always**. Then your question is 'how can I pass/show formatted text in a `p:messages`. And in your code above, the DB access is totally irrelevant. A static array would have the same problem. And hence it is not java or arrays related and those tags are therefore wrong.

Comment: Just loop over it and add each entry as new message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `<p:messages>` component will handle multiple messages. Just make sure you've put one in the xhtml page that will be rendered or updated after the action is complete.

So, in your backing bean you should just iterate through messages[] and add faces messages, just as @BalusC suggested.

```
        String[] messages = new String[] {
                "Record No.1 Fail",
                "Record No.2 Fail",
                "Record No.3 Success"
        };
        for(int i = 0 ; i < messages.length; i++){
            String msg = messages[i];
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, msg, null));
        }
```

The result would look like this :
[image]

By the way, you are not using the `details` option, so should use `showDetail="false"`